# Flatpak system-wide installation permission

Tags: flatpak

Flatpak installs system-wide application to `/var/lib/flatpak` on my Fedora 30. However, I'm not using sudo or any other privileged account, how can it write to this directory (the premission is `rwxr-xr-x`) without proper permission?

Comment: Is your user a member of the **sudo** group?

Comment: No, it's a member of the **wheel** group.

Comment: Does the wheel group have full access via sudo? If so, that's why you can install flatpaks without authenticating with root privileges.

Comment: Yes, it has full access via sudo, but if I'm using **dnf** to install some packages, I have to use sudo every time, otherwise it will fails. Why dnf and flatpak differ in this way?

Comment: We had a conversation about this recently - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169479/how-to-force-flatpak-to-ask-for-a-password - and were unable to figure out how to disable this "feature". I can't find any documentation on this, and it affects every version of Linux I've installed over the past year.